# @Requestmapping("/") produces 404 with Spring MVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have the DispatcherServlet configured for the url-patten of "/".

Now, I have the following controller code:

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

  @RequestMapping("/")
  public void home() {
      System.out.print("Test");
  }
}
```

If the value within the `@RequestMapping` is just `/`, when I deploy and go to `http://host/webapp/`, I get a 404, however, if I change it to `/*`, the console will print `Test`.

I understand why `/*` works as it basically catches any path, including just `/` because `*` can be 0 or more chars, but why does simply mapping to `/` not work for me?

More than than how to get it to work, I am interested in the "WHY". I see plenty of examples on the web where `@RequestMapping("/")` is used and no one seems to say that it's wrong. So, WHY would it not for me? I'd like to understand what's going on.

Any help would be appreciated!

Here is my WebApplicationInitializer:

```
public class MyWebInitializer
  implements WebApplicationInitializer {

  @Override
  public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext)
    throws ServletException {

    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    context.setConfigLocation("com.web");
    context.setServletContext(servletContext);
    servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(context));
    context.refresh();

    ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = servletContext
      .addServlet("DispatcherServlet", new DispatcherServlet(context));
    dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    dispatcher.addMapping("/");
    System.out.println("WebInitializer.onStartup is complete");
  }
}
```

Here is my Java Config which is in the "com.web" package pointed to by `context.setConfigLocation("com.web")` line:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan({"com.web"})
public class SpringConfig
  extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

  @Override
  public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    System.out.println("Configuring static resources.");
    registry.addResourceHandler("/css/**").addResourceLocations("/css/");
  }

  @Bean
  public ViewResolver configureViewResolver() {
    InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
    viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");

    return viewResolver;
  }
}
```

Why doesn't the `@RequestMapping("/")` not get executed in the `HomeController` class?

Comment: It should work. Even spring documemtation has such an example, See the second listing in http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping

Comment: That's what I thought as well... So, what could be the reasons it doesn't? I'll paste my config (java-based) into the question. Maybe I am not loading it correctly, but it's hard to see what's wrong.

Comment: Are you deploying on Tomcat? and if yes which version?

Answer (score 0):

Change the RequestMapping to below if you want it to hit only "/"

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

Give that a go and let me know how it works out for you.

Then if you want to add say index to the parameter add the value parameter:

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/","/index},method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

Comment: The first one makes sense. It will catch ANY GET request. The second one is what I am not 100% understanding. First, method = RequestMethod.GET is not needed. It works without it as well as that's a default anyway. However, why adding "/index" makes both work (i.e., / and /index) is something I don't get. Why doesn't just "/" work??? Are there docs in Spring that talk about /index and what it does to enable / to work?

Comment: In fact, I just tried and even "/index" works by itself to map host/webapp/ to the method. Is there some documentation you can point me to that says this. I can't find any.

Comment: /index by itself will work, / by itself won't as you mentioned. also metho = RequestMethod.GET is not necessary in the second case, it will automatically assume GET calls go there by default. personally it was a combination of reviewing the API, reference documentation and experimentation